# Generating HD wallet seed phrase

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, wallet-security, seed

got a new hardware wallet and thinking of using my own set of bip39 words instead of wallet generated one, combined with a passphrase.

Comment: To create a secure wallet, you need a good source of entropy. Humans are **terrible** sources of entropy. I would definitely not recommend doing this, use a proper source of entropy instead if you want to create your own seed phrase manually (eg, rolling well-balanced dice).